# How do I navigate my Windows folders like C drive in MSYS?

Tags: bash, msys

How do I navigate through my Windows folder structure within the MSYS shell? When I start the shell, all I see is a '~'. I type 'ls' and the folder is empty. I just want to know how to get to my c drive.

Comment: Just a small note: the `~` indicates that you are in the current user's (i.e. your) home directory.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`cd /c/` to access C:

`cd /d/` for D:

etc.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the first / in front of the drive letter.

Comment: It is easy to miss as that doesn't show up when doing a `ls /` command. :(  I think that should be filed as a bug.

Comment: Why is that `/c`, `/d`, etc. are not shown when I do `ls -la /` ?

Answer (score 23):

Your `C:` drive is mounted on `/c` automatically by MinGW, just type `cd /c` to get in.

Comment: Why doesn't c drive show when you do `ls /` ?

Answer (score 22):

use `df` to see all mount point so you can navigate to them. my `df` output shows below:

```
    Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp
                      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /tmp
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0     76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /usr
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0     76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /
C:\MinGW\build32      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /build32
C:\MinGW\build64      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /build64
C:\MinGW\local32      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /local32
C:\MinGW\local64      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /local64
C:\MinGW\mingw32      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /mingw32
C:\MinGW\mingw64      76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /mingw64
C:\MinGW\opt          76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /opt
C:\MinGW\src          76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /src
c:                    76694276  46239412  30454864  61% /c
d:                    62471380  33791832  28679548  55% /d
e:                   163839996 129349800  34490196  79% /e
f:                   266237948 222816904  43421044  84% /f
g:                   407410152 346169248  61240904  85% /g
h:                    65328288  22612768  42715520  35% /h
i:                   122881152  54066728  68814424  44% /i
j:                   409601240 176372780 233228460  44% /j
k:                   378949628  56153980 322795648  15% /k
```

Comment: In my case (MSYS2) `df` shows `C:\msys64  <-->  /`  and `E:  <-->  /e` but doesn't show `C:  <-->  /c`  Despite this, I can still navigate to that folder via `cd /c`

Comment: Yeah, I don't see all my drive mounts either.  This should be filed as a bug.

Comment: I can only get `C:/msys64  <-->  /` when executing `df` . If I add the `-a` or `--all` parameter, then two mount points `C:/msys64/usr/bin  <-->  /bin` and `C:  <-->  /c` will appear. I'm using "msys2-runtime 3.2.0-3".